# Does creating symlink from another symlink in clearcase is advisable?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

In my clearcase view , I copied a symlinks from one component to another component thought that symlink will always point to target file.

But when i see the property it is referring the parent symlink now. I think it will not have any problem as when parent symlink is changed then child symlink also will be reflected.

does it have problem with this (symlink to symlink) approach ? (one problem is if i need to see the original file , now i need to warp to symlink twice ).

Should i delete and point to original file ?

Answer (score 1):

I would rather delete and replace it with a pointer to the original, with a:

```
 cleartool ln -slink -nc ../../some_file.txt
```

(It is recommended that you use relative VOB symbolic links instead of absolute symbolic links)

Depending on an intermediate target (which can be deleted -- unreference -- at any time) seems unsafe.

You can try and edit your copied link, in order to change its target, but the problem here, as mentioned in [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118146), is that:

> The only way to revise a VOB symbolic link to a relative path is to create a new symbolic link.
>   You cannot edit (revise) a VOB symbolic link if it has been created using an absolute path to utilize a relative path.